# Kotlin function returns null

Tags: kotlin

This function always returns null. t is not being assigned with token value. can someone help pls?

```
fun getToken(): String? {
    var t: String? = ""
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { token: String? ->
        Log.i(TAG,"Token: ${token.toString()}")
        t = token
    }.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? ->
        Log.e(TAG,"Couldn't get token", e)
    }
    return t
  }
```

Comment: The only way this function returns null, is when the token value actually IS assigned. It just happens to be `null`, for a reason unknown to me. What does the documentation of Firebase say about `null` as token value?

Answer (score 2):

`getToken` is returning `null` because this function completes before the success listener is invoked. `getToken` doesn't wait for the request to complete. The only thing it does is setting up the success and failure listeners which will be invoked when the request returns a response.

There are a few ways to solve this problem:

- Mark `getToken` as `suspend` and use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.await()` to wait until the response is received.
- Instead of returning the token, you can pass a callback to `getToken` which will be invoked when the response comes.

  ```kotlin
  fun getToken(onTokenReceive: (String?) -> Unit) {
      FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { token: String? ->
          Log.i(TAG,"Token: ${token.toString()}")
          onTokenReceive(token)
      }.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? ->
          Log.e(TAG,"Couldn't get token", e)
          onTokenReceive(null)
      }
  }
  ```

  So if your were earlier calling the function like this:

  ```kotlin
  val token = getToken()
  // using the `token` here
  ```

  Now you can change it to this:

  ```kotlin
  getToken { token ->
      // use the `token` here
  }
  ```